# How to limit memory size in mongo v3.4

Tags: mongodb, caching

In v4.0.12 or later, **wiredTigerMaxCacheOverflowSizeGB** option is available to specify the maximum size of "lookaside table" file. 
Is there any parameter which can limit the memory usage in mongo v3.4?

Comment: MongoDB 3.4 doesn't even have a lookaside table.

Answer (score 1):

wiredTigerMaxCacheOverflowSizeGB limits disk usage, not memory usage.

For memory usage on 3.4 I use:

```
--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 0.25
```

WiredTiger memory usage: [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#memory-diagnostics-for-the-wiredtiger-storage-engine)

Tell MongoDB how much memory exists in the system: [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#how-do-i-calculate-how-much-ram-i-need-for-my-application)

Note that generally, limiting the memory available to the database (such as through system-level configuration) is not useful because if such a limit is reached, the database process will typically immediately terminate. Instead one generally would either:

- Understand how much memory is required for the workloads being executed, and provision that much memory for the database, or
- Limit workloads to use the memory which is available (for example through adding indexes or sharding the data).

Comment: As per my understanding, wiredTigerCacheSizeGB will only limit the internal cache but the memory usage of mongo process cannot be limited using this. Could you please confirm how to limit the memory usage of Mongo processes?

Comment: You can limit memory available to MongoDB (such as by using Docker memory limits, potentially ulimit limits) but when the database exceeds them it'll just die. It is more effective to limit how much memory the database is configured to use which is done through database configuration, not externally.

Comment: Could you please let me know, how to check the database configuration for memory usage. I could not find any relevant documentation of any such configurations.
Also, Could you please confirm if any upgraded version of Mongo supports memory limitation on its own?

Comment: You can start by reading [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#memory-diagnostics-for-the-wiredtiger-storage-engine).

Answer (score 0):

Limiting database memory is a database anti-pattern. The primary goal of a database is to keep your working set in memory. if you really want limit memory consumption run MongoDB inside a container with a memory cap.